# "var" was previously used as a variable - MatLab

Tags: matlab

I don't know why it tells me that I previously used as a variable when I have never used it before.

Here is my code:

```
price := 0;
temp := 0;

for i=1:m,
    price += -y(i)*log( sigmoid(theta'*X(i,:)) ) -(1-y(i))*log(1-sigmoid(theta'*X(i,:)) );  
end;

J = price / m;

for i=1:n,
    temp := 0;
    for i2=1:m,    
        temp += ( 1-sigmoid(theta'*X(i2,:)) - y(i2) ) * X(j,i2);   
    end;    
    grad(i) = temp;    
end;
```

The error is here:

```
'price += -y(i)*log( sigmoid(theta'*X(i,:)) ) -(1-y(i))*log(1-sigmoid(theta'*X(i,:)) );'
```

**Log error**:
*"price" was previously used as a variable, conflicting with its use here as the name of a function or command.
See "How MATLAB Recognizes Command Syntax" in the MATLAB documentation for details.*

Comment: That's not valid Matlab code, neither `:=` or `+=` are allowed.  `:=` is part of MuPad, not the Matlab language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess there is nothing like `+=` in Matlab. So, you can't do the following.

```
price += -y(i)*log(sigmoid(theta'*X(i,:))) - (1-y(i))*log(1-sigmoid(theta'*X(i,:)));
```

Rather you should do the following.

```
price = price + -y(i)*log(sigmoid(theta'*X(i,:))) -(1-y(i))*log(1-sigmoid(theta'*X(i,:)));
```

Moreover, `:=` is not allowed according to Matlab language. Perhaps, your code is in [Mupad](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad-1.html). Check [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/_assign.html) out.

Comment: Thanks a lot Wasi! I am new in MatLab haha. Have a great day!

Comment: @MichaelSzer best way to thank is through accepting the answer :)